# Is there a PHP validation site or testing site on the web?

Tags: php, validation, testing

Is there a validation site for PHP similar to the ones for [css](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) or [html](http://validator.w3.org/)?  Even better, are there any site on the web similar to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) where you can create and test the code?

Comment: i use http://codepad.org/ now and then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's one that compares to JSFiddle I guess, here: [Codepad Viper](http://codepad.viper-7.com/)

Answer (score 2):

http://ideone.com - it supports *a lot* of programming languages